# Why new added Maven module in cloned repo generate a main branch can't be used?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I recently create an empty repo in Gitee and use IDEA to clone it and then add five maven modules, as you can see the original cloned repo is on master branch but the new added are on main branch which I can't use, **I just want to know why a new main will appear and how can i use it to commit&push to Gitee**.

And when I try to commit, the .gitignore file in root directory seems not working because the mvnw and mvnw.cmd still in the commit dialog, why and how can I solve it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you checkout these branches from CMD?
2. Files are still there because they have already been added to git. If a file is already tracked by git, after putting it in the .gitignore it must be removed from git index, you need to use **git rm --cached [file]** command to remove it.